# How to resolve Error: Unexpected token '<' in Asp.Net request?

Tags: asp.net, json, request, webmethod, jsonserializer

I am trying to call a WebService in my `ASP. Net` app and am getting the following error: `Error:  Unexpected token '<'`. So far it seems like a `json` parsing issue, but I am not sure how to resolve it. In my app, I have a data manager that calls a stored procedure from a local `SQL .mdf` database. Essentially, its a public `DataTable` called  GetEventsByState() and it is stored in my `DataAcessManager.cs` file. It is called from a WebService in my App_Service.asmx.cs file. The goal is to return the `datatable` as json in the `WebService` so I can then call it in my `app.js` file:

RII_Service.cs

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetListOfEventsByState()
    {
        _dtMgr = new DataAccessManager();
        //string state = st;
        /*HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(GetEventsData());*/
        DataTable EventsList = _dtMgr.GetEventsByState();
        var lst = EventsList.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => r.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(c.ColumnName, r[c.Ordinal])
                ).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Value)
            ).ToList();
        //now serialize it
        try
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);
            json = json.TrimEnd();
            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This `WebMethod` is then called in `app.js` on page load like this:

app.js

```
//Function to call Asp.Net Web Service and retrieve events list by state
var EventsData = esriRequest({
    url: "RII_Service.asmx/GetListOfEventsByState",
    content: {
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    handleAs: "json"
});
EventsData.then(
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        events_json = response;
....
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error.message);
});
```

When I put break points on RII_Service.cs for the `WebMethod` GetListOfEventsByState(), it produces a viable json string that looks like this:

`"[{\"FullEventName\":\"NJ Cindy 2005\",\"State\":\"NJ\"},{\"FullEventName\":\"NJ Gordon 2000\",\"State\":\"NJ\"}...]`

However when it goes back to the `EventsData` request, it goes right to the error. Any clues or suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Check the response when you're getting that error. In my experience, that usually indicates that you're expecting a JSON response, but instead got an HTML response (e.g. a server error).

Comment: The error response doesn't give me more than `error = SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' `, but it does seem like its dragging in the HTML `<string>` tag and that's what's throwing the error. Idea's on how to get around that? Is there a setting in my `request` in `app.js` that's not right (jsonp?)?

Comment: What response is coming from the server though?

Comment: Hey @Matt U, I figured it out. See my answer below. You were correct about the HTML response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with the xml/html being pulled over to the `app.js` request when making a call to the WebMethod in RII_Service.cs. Despite `GetListOfEventsByState()` showing a `json string` being returned, the `<string>` tag would always get picked up on the `app.js` side (thus explaining the `'<'` error). To resolve this, I did 2 things. First, serialized it using the `NewtonSoft.Json` method `JsonConvert`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

*You might have to install this using Tools > NuGet Package first. I then used `System.Web.HttpContext` to format the output. So, I reworked my WebMethod `GetListOfEventsByState()` as follows and it worked. Hope this helps anyone having similar issues:

```
    [WebMethod]
    //public string GetListOfEventsByState()
    public void GetListOfEventsByState()
    {
        _dtMgr = new DataAccessManager();
        DataTable EventsList = _dtMgr.GetEventsByState();

        //now serialize it
        try
        {
            string JSONresult;
            JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EventsList);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JSONresult);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```